# Significant amount of foreign coins from 6 different countries

Tags: usa, money

Collected coins from ship mates to change into dollars for a donation. Have anywhere from 3-6 pounds of coins from each country. Need a US company/ financial institution that will exchange the coins for dollars.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think money-changers accept foreign coins at all, only notes. And when you buy currency they only supply notes, with the purchase fee in exact local currency. Perhaps a numismatist shop will buy them.

Comment: Exchange of foreign _coins_ requires so large volumes to make economic sense that it's only barely a travel question. You'd need to find a _very_ specialized processor. Perhaps there's a better chance that [Money.SE] knows one, though the topicness of the question is a bit iffy there too.

Comment: I know in the UK when you go to currency exchange places you can donate any type of currency you might have left from your holiday, maybe you can do this in the US?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to an airport where Virgin Atlantic flies, see if they will accept it. They have ["Change for Children"](https://www.virginatlantic.com/gb/en/sustainability/community/change-for-children.html) appeal where they will accept pocket change in any currency on flights. I would try to call and speak to a manager first.